# Densesness of irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers

Given $Q$: the aggregate of the rational numbers and $R$: the aggregate of the real numbers and $Qc$: the aggregate of the irrational numbers; Give $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \text{ with } x < y$.

Show that one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and one $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ hast to exist, so:

$x < r  +  $$\frac{\sqrt 2}{n}$ $< y$

Answer (score 1):

The needed property is
provided by the
Archimedean axiom.
See, for example,
here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property

One form states that,
for any real $z > 0$,
there is an integer $n$
such that
$\dfrac1{n} < z$.

Now apply this to
$\dfrac1{n} <(y-x)/2$
and look at the
consecutive multiples
of $\dfrac1{n}$
or $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$.

---

More detail.

Let $k$ be the first multiple of
$\dfrac1{n}$ such that
$\dfrac{k}{n} > x$.
This means that
$\dfrac{k-1}{n} \le x$.
These mean
$k > nx$
and
$k-1 \le nx$
so
$k = 1+\lfloor nx \rfloor
$.

Consider
$w
=\dfrac{k+1}{n}
=\dfrac{k}{n}+\dfrac1{n}
$.

From
$\dfrac1{n} <(y-x)/2$
we get

$\begin{array}\\
w
&=\dfrac{k}{n}+\dfrac1{n}\\
&\lt\dfrac{k}{n}+\dfrac{y-x}{2}\\
&\lt x+\dfrac1{n}+\dfrac{y-x}{2}\\
&\lt x+\dfrac{y-x}{2}+\dfrac{y-x}{2}\\
&=y\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\dfrac{k}{n}$
and
$\dfrac{k+1}{n}$
are two rationals
that are between
$x$ and $y$.

If we specify $n$ by
$\dfrac1{n}
\lt \dfrac{y-x}{m}$,
where $m$ is a positive integer,
we can find
$\dfrac{k+j}{n}$
which are between
$x$ and $y$
for $j = 0$ to $m-1$.

If we choose $m=3$,
then
$\dfrac{k}{n}$,
$\dfrac{k+1}{n}$,
and
$\dfrac{k+2}{n}$,
are all between $x$ and $y$,
so that
$\dfrac{k+\sqrt{2}}{n}$
is between
$x$ and $y$.

Comment: So this is the proof?

Comment: I don't get it, how the consecutive multiples of 1/n prove that?

Comment: I added some additional explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know how to prove that, if x< y are two irrational numbers, then there exist an irrational number, r, between them: x< r< y?

Comment: No, sadly not..